# Do I need a departure flight booked to apply for a UK Tier 5 Youth Mobility visa?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, working-visas, working-holiday

I've booked a one way ticket to the UK and am in the process of applying for a Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa. I got a one way ticket as I'm not sure whether I will stay the whole 2 years/if I will move on some where else afterwards etc. 
My question is, do I need to have proof of a flight departing the UK to be granted a visa? I've heard some countries require this as evidence that you intend to leave once your visa expires. Thanks.

Comment: Don't book your ticket before you get your visa!!! The UK visa guidance is quite clear that you do not need a ticket before you get a visa. Now, if your visa is denied, you've wasted a lot of money on a plane ticket, unless you got a refundable one.

Answer (score 0):

The document requirements page for Tier 5 youth mobility visa doesn't list return flight ticket.

As a general rule of thumb, return flights are not required for work and long term study visas.

Comment: This would be a perfect answer if it linked to the document requirements page it mentions.  Any chance of that?